# Queuing URLs and Asynchronous Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, queue

I have the following code that I use with wappalyzer to scrape the technology data of a website.

```
const wappalyzer = require('wappalyzer');
var fs = require('fs');

var myArray =[http://www.url1.com, http://www.url2.com ...]   // it's a very 
long array of URLs

var dataSlice = myArray.slice(0, 1000);  

console.log(dataSlice);
fs.appendFileSync('webData.json', '[', 'utf8');

var done = {};
var count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < dataSlice.length; i++) {
  (function(i){
    wappalyzer.run([dataSlice[i], '--quiet'], function(stdout, stderr) {
      //Keep track of when all urls are done

      if(!done[i]){
        done[i] = true;
        count++;

        if ( stdout ) {
          var arr = stdout.split('\n');
          stdout  = arr.filter(function(elem, pos) {
              return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
          });
          stdout = stdout.join('');
          stdout = count >= dataSlice.length ? (stdout + ']') : (stdout + 
',');
          fs.appendFileSync('WebData.json', stdout, 'utf8');
        }

      }

      if ( stderr ) {
        process.stderr.write(stderr);
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

The problem is I have a very large list of URLs that I run through this loop so I slice the array into smaller sections to do ~1000 at a time however, when I do any more the systemfreezes as it uses quite a bit of CPU, how would I run this code asynchronously and queue up URLs? Also is there a simple NPM package to intall? I've had a look around and haven't found anything easy to work with.

Comment: Perhaps async/await + promises can be of some help? if you node version supports it

Comment: I had a look at bluebird but couldn't really understand it, I'm kinda new.

Comment: what node version do you use?

Comment: 8.1.3

could I do it through this?

Comment: async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});

Answer (score 0):

you can do a ring buffer.

the idea is to have an array of pending task, have one loop (in node the loop must be async to not block the engine) which does the job to refill and start jobs, with callbacks you can watch for begin/end of tasks.

beware to not overwrite ring in a callback, as you ll see i always copy it from call to call and write it in sync.

if i m correct, below should do the job.

```
// concurrent/async job processing.
function main() {

  var consumer = function(todo, done){ // execute whatever to do.
    console.log("start ", todo.id, todo.duration);
    setTimeout(function(){
      done();
      console.log("done ", todo.id, todo.duration);
    }, todo.duration);
  };

  var id = 0;
  function reader(len) { // a dummy function that provides n new jobs
    var ret = []
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      ret.push({
        id: id,
        duration:getRandomInt(250, 1000),
        about: "whatever todo",
        status: "todo"
      });
      id+=1;
    }
    return ret
  };

  var ring = []; // the ring contains the element being processed
  var loop = function(){ // is async
    ring = processor(ring, 10, reader, consumer);
    logger(ring);
    setTimeout(loop, 100); // loop here.
  };loop();

};process.nextTick(main);

function processor(ring, concurrency, reader, consumer){
  ring = ring.filter(notStatus('done')); // remove done jobs
  var delta = concurrency-ring.length;
  if(delta>0) { // refill the ring until it is full
    ring = ring.concat(reader(delta))
  }
  ring.filter(byStatus('todo')).forEach(function(todo){ // select those todo
    todo.status = 'started';
    consumer(todo, function(){
      todo.status = "done";
    })
  })
  return ring
}

function logger(ring){
  console.log("   ring");
  ring.forEach(function(todo){
    console.log("   ", todo.status, todo.id, todo.duration);
  });
}

function byStatus(s){
  return function(todo){return todo.status==s}
}

function notStatus(s){
  return function(todo){return todo.status!=s}
}

// .... still not std ?
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Probably works, but I have no idea how to implement it with the code that I have and I kinda want to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: copy / paste it in a file, `index.js`, appropriately update the code to realize whatever you need, run `node index.js`. That won t work in browser.